# Can a 'before' clause function as a noun complement?

Tags: relative-clauses, prepositional-phrases, subordinate-clauses

> It was a time **before I knew you**.

In this sentence, the subordinate clause 'before I knew you' acts as an adjectival noun complement to 'time'. 'Before' is not a relative adverb that I am aware of, so what is happening here?

The best explanation I could think of is that there is an omitted object after 'before' (see the example below).

> It was a time **before the time when I knew you**.

By expanding the sentence like this, we can see that 'before' becomes a preposition. The noun 'time' is repeated and modified by the relative clause 'when I knew you'.

Is this an appropriate explanation, or am I completely off track?

Comment: "Before" is always a preposition, so "before I knew you" is a PP functioning here as a temporal adjunct, not a complement. The adjunct locates the time as being "before I knew you". The PP in your suggestion expresses the same meaning, but it is overly wordy and not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

This books says *before* has an interpretation in traditional grammar of preposition, subordinating conjunction, and adverb. With a clause as complement, your first example would seem to have *before* as a conjunction. They argue that it is a preposition in all of its uses, but with different types of complement.

[Student's Introduction to English Grammar](https://books.google.com/books?id=AMAgAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA129&dq=The%20traditional%20class%20of%20subordinating%20conjunctions%20contains&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi6p4u6qfPzAhWCWM0KHYpsAaEQ6AF6BAgLEAI#v=onepage&q=The%20traditional%20class%20of%20subordinating%20conjunctions%20contains&f=false)

> But traditional grammar treats *before* in a completely different way. It is treated
> as a preposition in [i], a *subordinating conjunction* in [ii], and an adverb in [iii].
> We see this triple assignment as an unnecessary complication. It is much simpler to
> give *before* a uniform analysis, **treating it as a preposition in all three**, just as *know* is a verb in all three.

[emphasis added]

The  example [ii] that has a clause as complement is this:
*That was before he died.*

That example seems quite similar to your example
*It was a time before I knew you*.
since in both cases, the clause is used to identify a point in time.

According to this book, then, *before* can be a preposition with a clause as a complement.